# Creating a form for discord using Nextcord and Python

Tags: python, discord

```
import nextcord
import nextcord.ui

class PurchaseForm(nextcord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super().__init__()

        self.add_item(nextcord.ui.Select(
            placeholder='Select a unit',
            options=[
                nextcord.SelectOption(label=unit, value=unit) for unit in units
            ],
            custom_id='unit_select',
        ))

        self.add_item(nextcord.ui.TextInput(
            label='Number of units',
            placeholder='Enter the number of units',
            custom_id='num_units_input',
        ))
```

Error:
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In components.1.components.0: Value of field "type" must be one of (2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8).

https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.ui.TextInput
I've tried looking at the Nextcord docs and I couldn't find anything about this error. The TextInput exists.

I've also tried chatgbt and got the answer:

```
The error message you're seeing, HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body, is raised when the bot attempts to send a message to Discord, and the structure of the message components (buttons, select menus, etc.) is not valid according to Discord's API specifications.

The specific part of the error message, In components.1.components.0: Value of field "type" must be one of (2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8), indicates that there's an issue with the type of a component within the message. Discord expects the "type" field of a component to be one of the following values:

2: Select Menu
3: Multi-Select Menu
5: Button
6: Action Row (Container for other components)
7: Select Menu Option
8: Button (Deprecated, you should use type 5 for buttons)
In the context of the components.1.components.0, it suggests that the issue is with the first component (index 0) inside the second row (index 1) of your message components.

To resolve this issue, you should ensure that each component within the view is correctly specified and adheres to the allowed types. In the code provided, the second row (text_input_row) contains a TextInput component, and it should be a valid type for a text input field. However, it seems there might be an issue.
```

Comment: Solved: Turns out that TextInput is not supported in views and only in modals